# Как показать изображение в ячейках?

Tags: ios, swift, изображения

У меня есть `TableViewController` и `AudioPlayerViewController`. В `TableViewController` я хочу знать, сколько треков было прослушано. И показать изображение только в прослушанных ячейках. Чтобы определить, что трек прослушан, я использую этот код в `AudioPlayerViewController`:

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
     UserDefaults.standard.set( arrayOfListened(trackIndex), forKey: "key") 
}
```

А чтобы показать изображение в ячейках в `TableViewController`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "cell", indexPath.row), for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

    if indexPath.row == arrayOfListened[indexPath.row] {
        cell.cellStatusImage.image = UIImage(named: "statusDone.png")
    }
                
}
```

Но мое приложение вылетает -  index out of range. Как это исправить?

Comment: Добавьте больше кода. Что есть arrayOfListened и из каких данных строите таблицу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам, при генерации ячейки, сначала необходимо получить сохранённый массив из UserDefaults, а затем поменять условие отображения картинки

`if arrayOfListened.contains(indexPath.row)`...